# HTML5 semantic element for Tip/Warning/Error pullouts?

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-markup, wai-aria

I am using XML-safe HTML5 and would like to know the semantic way of documenting extra tip/warning/error boxes (like those often found in technical manuals):

```
<div class="info-tip" role="contentinfo">
    <p><strong>Tip:</strong> Holding the control key when doing this will make life easier.</p>
</div>
```

Except if possible I would like to use a more appropriate element. I am not even sure if `contentinfo` is an appropriate choice here.

**ADDED:** I am after a HTML5 alternative of the `<note>` element in DITA.

**A little context:** I will be using stylesheets (both XSLT2 and CSS) to re-format the content for a number of outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semantically closest one seems to be the `<details>` element - [usage](http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/)